# Private framework is not recognized by App Extension

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks

I'm following [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/6462-siri-shortcuts-tutorial-in-ios-12) tutorial about Siri Shortcuts and I'm having an issue that is unrelated to the topic of the tutorial.

In the tutorial, we have an app extension for handling the intent-based shortcuts. We also have a private framework called `ArticleKit` which does the actual work and is called by our extension. The problem I'm having is that when I try to run the project, I'm getting the following error:
`No such module 'ArticleKit'`.
This is weird because I downloaded the starter project and the error was there in the first place.

In other words, the app extension does not recognize the framework. What do I need to change so that it does recognize it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the framework to the extension's target too. Here's the steps:

1. Choose the project file from file navigator in Xcode.
2. Choose the extension target from targets.
3. In the general tab, add your framework in the Frameworks, Libraries,.. category.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm getting the same error unfortunately.

Comment: Add the screenshot.